# Cronjob command not running

Tags: cron

I have cronjob as below

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot --use-iam-role --mysql --description "Snapshot on $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" --tag="Name=snapshotname" vol-id > ~/cron.log
```

When I just run the command from terminal, it works but cronjob does not work.

```
/usr/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot --use-iam-role --mysql --description "Snapshot on $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" --tag="Name=snapshotname" vol-id > ~/cron.log
```

Is there any mistake in my cronjob formatting? I am using this on ubuntu 13.10 in Aws ec2.

Comment: not sure it was the same as a problem I had, but I had to put the cron job on my root user to execute correctly

Comment: I am just noticing that 0 0 * ... How often did you want this to execute?

Comment: every day @samuel.molinski

Comment: Should i do sudo crontab -e

Comment: Try using the sudo crontab -e.  That looks right for everyday at midnight.  Try much smaller interval for testing until you know it is working with the current permission, then swap it.